# Exporting Firestore to Cloud Storage using a cloud function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, database-backups

I have a cloud function calling [exportDocuments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases/exportDocuments) that looks like this:

```
client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('firestore', 'v1beta1')
client.projects().databases().exportDocuments(name=name, body=body).execute()
```

It is crashing due to an authentication error:

```
HttpError 403 "The caller does not have permission"
```

The cloud function is crashing when triggered using Pub/Sub. 
But if I run the same code from Cloud Shell, it works.

*My questions are:*

- Am I doing it wrong? Should't the auth be handled automagically since I'm executing in a cloud function? I mean it's working from Cloud Shell.
- What can I do? Example code more than welcome as I cannot wrap my head around authenticating manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Function service account has the [project Editor role by default](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export#before_you_begin). This role does not include permissions to start Cloud Firestore exports.

You can follow [steps 3 and 4 here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export#before_you_begin) to give the default service account, `YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, permissions to start Cloud Datastore/Firestore exports and to access your designated Cloud Storage bucket.